# Visual Studio 2019 hangs on "Execute Suggested Action" when adding a reference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've got a problem with Visual Studio Enterprise 2019, it hangs on "Execute Suggested Action" when I use it to add a reference to another project or library.

[image]

Comment: This may be something to ask at the Microsoft forums.

Comment: Same for me, on 2 different computers. Vs 16.8.2

Comment: Same annoying behaviour on Version 16.8.3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a Visual Studio bug. They are working on it.
Take a look here: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Infinite-suggested-action-never-ends/1223055

The fix will be probably released on the next release (16.9).

**UPDATE:**
Still in vs 16.8.4 but should be solved in 16.9.

**UPDATE 2:**
In 16.9 PREVIEW 3, this issue seems to be resolved.

**UPDATE 3:**
Fix has been released! You can download the new version of VS now.

Comment: unfortunately I've installed the preview version but the problem is still there :(

Comment: Yes, I know... Others have just reported that the issue is still here. You can check it on the link I've posted above. Wait and wish :)

Comment: Still exists in VS2022. Had it hang on the automated 'add nuget package' suggested action. Lost loads of work.

Answer (score 4):

if anyone struggle with adding references: go to your project -> right click on Dependencies -> select eg Add Project Reference -> look for proper reference [image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when adding on the suggestion of Intellisense. For me, it turned out to be an issue of cyclic reference. My bad. I corrected it and now it doesn't hang.

It was VS 2019 community, Windows Forms (C#)